# python - apply(lambda x: ...) function applied to dictionary value when value is a Series or a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda, apply

I am trying to use the apply(lambda x: ...) function on a dictionary value which is a dataframe but get the ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). I know that this works on a dataframe column. But I want to know if there is a way to use it on dictionary value. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['M','M','M','F','F','O1','O2'],
                   'A1':[2,4,8,7,6,4,5],'A2':[2,4,8,7,6,4,5],
                   'B1':[5,8,9,7,5,6,3]})
df
#>   Gender  A1  A2  B1
0      M   2   2   5
1      M   4   4   8
2      M   8   8   9
3      F   7   7   7
4      F   6   6   5
5     O1   4   4   6
6     O2   5   5   3
    
dct = {}
for cat in ['Gender','A','B']:
    dct[cat] = df[[c for c in df.columns if c.startswith(cat)]]
dct
#> {'Gender':   Gender
 0      M
 1      M
 2      M
 3      F
 4      F
 5     O1
 6     O2,
 'A':    A1  A2
 0   2   2
 1   4   4
 2   8   8
 3   7   7
 4   6   6
 5   4   4
 6   5   5,
 'B':    B1
 0   5
 1   8
 2   9
 3   7
 4   5
 5   6
 6   3}

## apply
g = dct['Gender'].apply(lambda x: 'Other' if x not in ['M','W'] else x]

#> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Desired Output**:

```
  Gender
0      M
1      M
2      M
3      F
4      F
5     Other
6     Other
```

***Questions:***

1. How can I pass a apply(lambda x: ...) function to a value (which is a Series or dataframe column) of a dictionary key ?
   Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
dct['Gender']['Gender'].apply(lambda x: 'Other' if x not in ['M','W'] else x)
# Output:
0        M
1        M
2        M
3    Other
4    Other
5    Other
6    Other
Name: Gender, dtype: object
```

`dct['Gender']` accesses the value as a whole (here, a dataframe)

```
type(dct['Gender'])
#> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

`dct['Gender']['Gender']` accesses the column within the dataframe that is the value. It then becomes possible to use the apply() function on that.

```
type(dct['Gender']['Gender'])
#> pandas.core.series.Series
```

**Documentation:**
*pandas.Series.apply*
Invoke function on values of Series.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [`pd.Series.str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) here. Pandas has has many [str methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) available leverage on them.

```
m = df['Gender'].str.fullmatch(r'[^MF]')
df.loc[m, 'Gender'] = 'Other'

print(df)
#   Gender  A1  A2  B1
# 0      M   2   2   5
# 1      M   4   4   8
# 2      M   8   8   9
# 3      F   7   7   7
# 4      F   6   6   5
# 5  Other   4   4   6
# 6  Other   5   5   3
```

- Details about *regex pattern* [`r'[^MF]'` in `Regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/3ppHte/1)

Comment: Would you please explain what do all the components within `r'[^MF]'` do or signify? What happens when you enclose with '[]'  within the str.match function? What does ^ do? Why is there no need to insert a comma between MF? How does r'xxx' help?

Comment: @rahul-ahuja That's a regex pattern. Details about [`regex pattern in Regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/3ppHte/1)

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner solution as `fullmatch` from Ch3steR's answer is not available to me (different version maybe?)

`df.loc[~df.Gender.isin(['M', 'F']),'Gender'] = 'Others'`